# React hooks, initialize and change state with onClick event using tables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, react-hooks

I am displaying a html table with a single field 'title'. Once the user clicks on one of the table rows I would like to display the corresponding title name below the table. It works fine using a dropdown list however when I try to convert it to a table, the state stops updating. (I've left the options attribute as a working example, however this needs to be removed or replaced). I would also like to display the first title in the table when the page first loads up (title[0]). I think this may require a useEffect. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import data from '../../data-files/data.json';

const TestPage = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

  const handleClick = e => {
    const selected = e.target.value;
    setTitle(selected);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <table
        cellPadding="0"
        cellSpacing="0"
        style={{ background: '#1A3D33', color: '#fff' }}
      >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th align="left">Title</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.data.map(i => (
            <tr key={i.id}>
              <td onClick={handleClick} style={{ background: '#439981' }}>
                <option>{i.name}</option>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <h3 style={{ marginTop: '50px' }}>{title}</h3>
    </>
  );
};

export default TestPage;
```

The data is coming from a local file:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "title 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "title 2"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "title 3"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "title 4"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "title 5"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't work without the `<option>` because the event isn't the same, you chould try passing the name as parameter to handle function:

```
  {data.data.map(i => (
    <tr key={i.id}>
      <td onClick={() => handleClick(i.name)} style={{ background: '#439981' }}>
        <option>{i.name}</option>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
```

Of course, if you do that change you will need to refactor `handleClick`

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my first issue. In-case anyone has the same issue. const handleClick = name => { setTitle(name)}